# What is "gullible" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

Did you know that Lewis and Short's dictionary doesn't contain the word "gullible"?
That is an appropriate question for the first of April, but it turns out that I indeed found no trace of that word.
Perhaps I'm missing English synonyms for someone who is naive and easily fooled.
What would be a good classical Latin word, noun or adjective, for this kind of a person?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps *[credulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=credulus&la=la#lexicon)*?

> *credula nec ravos timeant armenta leones*
>
> gullible cattle no longer fear tawny lions

Horace, *Epodes*, 16.33

> *Credula si fueris, aliae tua gaudia carpent*
>
> If you are gullible, other women will seize your joys

Ovid, *Ars Amatoria*, 3.661

> *Haec enim etiam in fabulis stultissima persona est improvidorum et
>   credulorum senum.*
>
> For even on the stage the silliest characters are improvident and
>   gullible old men.

Cicero, *De Amicitia*, 26.100

Comment: Looks perfect! I get the feeling that the diminutive adds a nuance of mockery, which I find appropriate.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, I overlooked that but I think you're right!

Comment: You even find it in English, albeit usually in the negated form (incredulous).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Which diminutive?

Comment: @DaG The *-ulus* in *credulus*. It could have been simply *credere > credus* (like *fidere > fidus*), but instead it's *credulus*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: I see. Are you sure that it is a diminutive? There other Latin adjectives in _-ulus_ that – I believe – are not diminutive, like [_sedulus_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sedulus&la=la&can=sedulus0&prior=rubicundulus#lexicon), _tremulus_ and so on. Again, I believe it is just a particular kind of word formation from some roots, but I'd like to hear from someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: @DaG No, I'm not sure at all whether that kind of *-ulus* should actually be understood as a diminutive. That would be a very interesting question to have on the site. If you want to go and ask it, I have an upvote waiting with your name on it. I'd be glad to understand all this better.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Great, thanks, good idea!

Answer (score 8):

The English verb 'gull' means 'deceive', and 'gullible' is derived from it. Penelope's *credulus* is excellent (and, indeed, is the word that I would choose), but I should like to point out *decipiendus* as an apt alternative.